# Add a node as a select list in Webforms Drupal 6?

Tags: webforms

I want to make a Webform in Drupal 6 where I can put a `<select>` list where the lists are a node. I already created a content type which is `events` and these events expires. So what I want is when the user submits a form he/she has the ability to select from the `<select>` list so when the form is submitted, when I go to the submission results, I can see the content type(`events`) which the user chose upon submitting the webform. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using D6 then consider the [Webform View Reference Component](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_viewreference) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... adds a webform component where you could use a View as a datasource for your normal webform select component. Instead of hardcoding all the selectable values in the component values field you just select a reference to a View similar to the CCK nodereference. The selectlist/radiobuttons/checkbox then automatically gets filled with all the nodes from the View.

Comment: how do I exactly use that?I already installed the module but still in my `select` field, my nodes are not available?

Comment: I personally haven't tried the module. But you should see another form element called as "Select View". So you add that component and in the select list you select the view which list all the nodes you want. If you need to learn how to use views then will have to use the advance help module to learn how to create views.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to explore around and found the `select view` list which contains all the nodes I want. Thanks a lot. :)